# How can I switch graphics from Intel to nVIDIA in ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: nvidia, 14.10, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 and it shows that I'm using `VESA: Intel® Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics`.

I don't really like the performance and I'm searching for a solution to switch on the nVIDIA GeForce 610M which is already installed on my ASUS?

Answer (score 0):

This might be just what you need:

https://github.com/beidl/prime-indicator

They say "*Indicator applet for Ubuntu 14.04 laptop users with NVIDIA/Intel switchable graphics*" but there is a good chance that it might also work for your version of Ubuntu.